# How to query multiple whereMonth in orWhere query for laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm newbie in Laravel and I need to do laravel query by getting result like below sql.

**SQL**

```
select * from `tb_project_participate` 
where 
    `project_id` = 20 and 
    `department_id` = 1 and 
    (
        month(`created_at`) = 10 or 
        (month(`created_at`) = 11) or 
        (month(`created_at`) = 12)
    )
```

Below is Laravel code that I use.

```
$participate = ProjectParticipate::where('project_id' , $project->project_id)
            ->where('department_id', $auth->department_id)
            ->whereMonth('created_at' , 10)
            ->orWhere(function($query){$query->whereMonth('created_at',11); })
            ->orWhere(function($query1){$query1->whereMonth('created_at',12); })
            ->get();
```

And I have result as below, that is not a query that I want.
**SQL**

```
select * from `tb_project_participate` 
where 
    `project_id` = 20 and 
    `department_id` = 1 and 
    month(`created_at`) = 10 or 
    (month(`created_at`) = 11) or 
    (month(`created_at`) = 12)
```

Appreciated for advice how to write Laravel query to get result as whsh, And so sorry for my English. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please google it first and foremost. I think this question has been answered tens of times on stackoverflow and hundreds or times on the web.

Try this:

```
$participate = ProjectParticipate::where('project_id' , $project->project_id)
                                ->where('department_id', $auth->department_id)
                                ->where(function($query){
                                $query->whereMonth('created_at' , 10);
                                $query->orWhere(function($query2){
                                   $query2->whereMonth('created_at',11); });
                                $query->orWhere(function($query1){
                                   $query1->whereMonth('created_at',12); });
                                })->get();
```

Or this (recomended):

We try to make code as general as possible so I want the months as a paramater.
No real reason for $auth either, since it's an extra operation to do: $auth = \Auth::user(). Just use \Auth::user()

```
$participate = ProjectParticipate::where('project_id' , $project->project_id)
                                   ->where('department_id', \Auth::user()->department_id)
                                   ->where(DB::RAW('month(created_at)'), $months)
                                   ->get();
```

Where $months is this array: [10,11,12]

Basically we have a query where we add all the or statements in. 
Check the manual for reference. You didn't mention the version, but not much change has been done in the last 3 years so here is the latest version: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#parameter-grouping

Comment: Hi, It should be a query like .... where a =1 and (b = 0 or c= 0 or d = 0) not .....where a =1 and b = 0 or c= 0 or d = 0

Answer (score 3):

try something like this

```
 $participate = ProjectParticipate::where('project_id' , $project->project_id)
                ->where('department_id', $auth->department_id)
                ->whereRaw('month(created_at) in (10,11,12))
                ->get()
```

or you can also do as

```
$participate = ProjectParticipate::where('project_id' , $project->project_id)
                ->where('department_id', $auth->department_id)
                ->whereIn(DB::raw('month(created_at)'),[10,11,12])
                ->get()
```

Comment: Hi this is wrong query, the equivalent to sql => select * from `tb_project_participate` where `project_id` = 20 and `department_id` = 1 and month(`created_at`) = 10 or (month(`created_at`) = 11) or (month(`created_at`) = 12). ...........................................................................................But I need like select * from `tb_project_participate` where `project_id` = 20 and `department_id` = 1 and (month(`created_at`) = 10 or (month(`created_at`) = 11) or (month(`created_at`) = 12))

Comment: instead using multiple or condition we can use in condition right?

Comment: select * from tb_project_participate where project_id = 20 and department_id = 1 and (month(created_at) = 10 or (month(created_at) = 11) or (month(created_at) = 12)) is equivalent to ProjectParticipate::where('project_id' , $project->project_id)->where('department_id', $auth->department_id)->where(function($query){$query->whereMonth('created_at',10)->orWhere(DB::raw('month(created_at)'),11)->orWhere(DB::raw('month(created_at)'),12)})->get();

Answer (score 0):

the accepted answer that recommended should be `whereIn` instead of `->where(DB::RAW('month(created_at)'), $months)`
Hope this helps others